# i got error SQLiteLog near "?"

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i got error **"SQLiteLog: (1) near "?": syntax error"**, any body know what's wrong with my code? i allready to try trial and error to fix this issue but still zero result..

here is caption for error log :

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "?": syntax error
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SyncVideoServices]
              Process: com.sbi.mvicall, PID: 11872
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax 
error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, caller_id, name, msisdn, pic, 
status, video, profiles FROM tbl_caller WHERE msisdn IN (?
```

here is my java code :

```
public String [] getRegisteredMSISDN(String [] msisdn){

    if(msisdn != null && msisdn.length > 0){
        String whereStatement = "";
        for(int i=0; i<msisdn.length; i++){
            whereStatement += ",";
            if(i==0){
                whereStatement += "(?";
            }
            else if(i==msisdn.length-1){
                whereStatement += "?)";
            }
            else{
                whereStatement += "?";
            }
        }

        whereStatement = whereStatement.substring(1);
        whereStatement = UserTable.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MSISDN + " IN " + whereStatement;

        SQLiteDatabase database = DBHelper
                .getInstance(applicationContext)
                .getReadableDatabase();

// =============== The error pointing code below ==============
        Cursor cursor = database.query(UserTable.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME, UserTable.ALL_COLUMNS, whereStatement, msisdn,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        String [] result = null;
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            int index = 0;
            result = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                result[index] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserTable.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MSISDN));
                index++;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you log your `whereStatement` just before `SQLiteDatabase database = DBHelper` ? and the error will appears

Comment: in this line right?
whereStatement = UserTable.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MSISDN + " IN " + whereStatement;

Answer (score 1):

Check your `if..else` statement for building `whereStatement`. If your `msisdn` has only 1 element, you will get `(?` in `whereStatement`.

Instead of adding `(` to first and `)` to last, just add `(` before cycle, and `)` after cycle. Also you need to do this only if `whereStatement.length > 0`

Comment: @Asqa, why can't you do it with my instructions from the question?

Comment: sorry, because this code is heritage from other developer, and iam still learning about SQLite

Comment: @Asqa, then it is even more important that you understand what that code does. What is not clear for you? Have you tried to debug it and solve by yourself?

Answer (score 1):

#### The Issue Explained

using the following :-

```
    String whereStatement = "";
    for(int i=0; i<msisdn.length; i++){
        whereStatement += ",";
        if(i==0){
            whereStatement += "(?";
        }
        else if(i==msisdn.length-1){
            whereStatement += "?)";
        }
        else{
            whereStatement += "?";
        }
    }
```

if msisdn has 1 value then

1. **i** will be **0** and therefore less than 1
2. **whereStatement** will be set to "**,**
3. **i** does equal **0** so
   3.a **whereStatement** will be set to **)?**
4. **`else`** will be skipped so the next iteration of the for loop commences and **i** is set to **1**.
5. **i** will not be less than **1** so the for loop finishes and you have **whereStatement** being **(?** and hence your issue.

---

#### The Fix

I believe the following will do what you need, as a replacement for the code above :-

```
        whereStatement = "("; // Add opening parenthesis
        for (int i = 0; i < msisdn.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                whereStatement += ","; // add a comma separator if not the first arg
            }
            whereStatement += "?"; // add the placement ? (for every arg)
        }
        whereStatement += ")"; // finally add the closing parenthesis
```

---

#### Testing

The following was used to test:-

```
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        String[] msisdn = new String[i+1];
        for (int j=0; j < msisdn.length; j++) {
            msisdn[j] = "Test" + String.valueOf(j);
        }
        buildWhereStatement(msisdn);
    }
```

With the `buildWhereStatement` method being :-

```
public void buildWhereStatement(String[] msisdn) {
    String whereStatement = "";
    if (msisdn != null && msisdn.length > 0) {

        whereStatement = "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < msisdn.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                whereStatement += ",";
            }
            whereStatement += "?";
        }
        whereStatement += ")";
    }
    Log.d("WHERESTMNT",whereStatement);
}
```

#### The result being :-

```
04-06 10:08:22.064 1367-1367/? D/WHERESTMNT: (?)
    (?,?)
    (?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```